# Gstreamer-java color distortion

Tags: java, video, colors, media-player, gstreamer

I am playing video with gstreamer using gstreamer-java.

When I move my program to ubuntu and play video with it, the red and blue colors are switched, like..the people's faces are blue.

If I run the same program on windows, I don't have any color problem..
I did some search on google and here is what i found
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+question/7373
I followed a lot of these people's suggestions here, but it still doesn't work on the ubuntu..
The Movie Player in ubunutu - totem (using gstreamer) can display the colors correctly for the same video file.

is there any way I can control gstreamer using gstreamer-java to change the color settings so it looks right?

Thanks！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the **XVideo (XV)** or **OpenGL** output. There is probably a problem in the graphics driver. One solution is to use *unaccelerated* **X11** output which is going to be **painfully slow**  but won't have the artifacts you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide gst-launch pipeline string which you should also be using in gstreamer-java api? From your description it looks like the image appears as RGB instead of BGR. This is due to video buffers being received as Big Endian in Java API. You may want to refer this patch on http://groups.google.com/group/gstreamer-java/msg/f93e7900d3028c51